# How can I remove internal padding on a RadioListTile so I can use 3 RadioListTiles in a row?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am pretty new to Flutter and Dart and I can't seem to find any hints for this particular topic.  I am trying to put 3 `RadioListTiles` in a `Row` like so:

```
Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child:RadioListTile<GoalSelection>(
              title: Text(
                'Net',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
              ),
              value: GoalSelection.net,
              groupValue: _goalSelection,
              onChanged: (GoalSelection value) {
                setState(() {
                  _goalSelection = value;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: RadioListTile<GoalSelection>(
              title: Text(
                'Gross',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
              ),
              value: GoalSelection.gross,
              groupValue: _goalSelection,
              onChanged: (GoalSelection value) {
                setState(() {
                  _goalSelection = value;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: RadioListTile<GoalSelection>(
              title: Text(
                'Salary',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
              ),
              value: GoalSelection.salary,
              groupValue: _goalSelection,
              onChanged: (GoalSelection value) {
                setState(() {
                  _goalSelection = value;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

The buttons layout fine, but there seems to be a lot of wasted space for the label.  I put a screenshot of what it currently looks like below.  I have tried wrapping the `Expanded`, the `RadioListTile`, and the `Text` in `Padding` widgets (all one at a time) to manually set the padding to 0, but it didn't do anything.  I have also tried to change `Expanded` to `Flexible` even though I didn't think that would change anything.  I am at a loss now.  Is there any way to get this layout to work?  I am kind of assuming it is something really dumb that I am doing.

[image: Layout inspector showing padding]

Answer (score 27):

You can use Radio + text widget instead of RadioListTile. For removing internal padding in Radio widget set:

```
                  Radio(
                    visualDensity: const VisualDensity(
                        horizontal: VisualDensity.minimumDensity,
                        vertical: VisualDensity.minimumDensity),
                    materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                    .....
                  ),
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use a `Radio` and `Text` widget in a row. But the `Radio` also has the same padding problem. To remove the padding you can put the `Radio` as a child of a `SizedBox`.

eg:- `SizedBox(height: 20, width: 20, child: Radio(.......))`

Answer (score 14):

`RadioListTile` is used with the purpose of taking the full width in a vertical scroll list.

If you don't want this behavior, don't use it. Use [`Radio`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Radio-class.html) instead.

Comment: The docs (and various GitHub issues) suggest that this is the implementation for a Radio with a label. I know you can make a row with a Radio and Text, but is there a way to tie the Text click to the Radio click?

Comment: @JasonToms wrap Text with GestureDetector and onTap do the same as onChanged of Radio

Comment: @Remi Remi - I have used both `RadioListTile` and `Radio`. Both are giving same output after giving contentPadding to zero. Any suggestion will be welcomed.

Comment: For Remi `Radio` solution code: return ListTile(
dense: true,
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
leading: Radio(
activeColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
value: int.parse(item['itemIndex']),
groupValue: _selectedItem,
onChanged: (val) {
_selectedItem = int.parse(val.toString());
setState(() {});
},
),
title: Text(
item['itemLabel'],
style:
Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
),
);

Comment: For Remi `RadioListTile` solution code: return RadioListTile(
title: Text(
item['itemLabel'],
style:
Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
),
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
dense: true,
activeColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
value: int.parse(item['itemIndex']),
groupValue: _selectedItem,
onChanged: (val) {
_selectedItem = int.parse(val.toString());
setState(() {});
},
);

Comment: @Remi Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

just set `contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero`

```
RadioListTile(contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero)
```

Comment: EdgeInsets.zero doesn't work..

Answer (score 4):

We can control the padding of the RadioListTile using Flexible widget. As you want to arrange 3 RadioListTiles inside a Row Widget. Please try with the below code, it will work.

```
 Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(
          fit: FlexFit.loose,
          child:
            RadioListTile(
              title: const Text('hello'),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
          ),
        Flexible(
          fit: FlexFit.loose,
          child:
            RadioListTile(
              title: const Text('Lafayette'),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
        )
      ],
    ),
```

Do, let me know. Once you tried with the above code. If it resolved you problem, please accept my answer as useful and provide your valuable comments.

Comment: nope, it doesn't work for 3 radio items in a row

Comment: @VipiNNegi Did you try the above or not. I have tried myself and posting here. If you have better solution, share it here. It will be helpful for others

Comment: I'm sorry mate, I tried again, exactly with same code above but with 3 radios on a row and result is exactly same as the image in OP image. Your answer is not really addressing the OP question. For now I've kept my radios in two lines which looks pretty decent for my case.

Comment: If possible, could you share the screenshot of the UI @VipiNNegi

Comment: this isn't resolve the appropriate issue.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem. You could try to customize with Radio, Text, InkWell, Padding.

```
class LabeledRadio extends StatelessWidget {
  const LabeledRadio({
    this.label,
    this.padding,
    this.groupValue,
    this.value,
    this.onChanged,
  });

  final String label;
  final EdgeInsets padding;
  final bool groupValue;
  final bool value;
  final Function onChanged;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        if (value != groupValue)
          onChanged(value);
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: padding,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Radio<bool>(
              groupValue: groupValue,
              value: value,
              onChanged: (bool newValue) {
                onChanged(newValue);
              },
            ),
            Text(label),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// ...

bool _isRadioSelected = false;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <LabeledRadio>[
        LabeledRadio(
          label: 'This is the first label text',
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
          value: true,
          groupValue: _isRadioSelected,
          onChanged: (bool newValue) {
            setState(() {
              _isRadioSelected = newValue;
            });
          },
        ),
        LabeledRadio(
          label: 'This is the second label text',
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
          value: false,
          groupValue: _isRadioSelected,
          onChanged: (bool newValue) {
            setState(() {
              _isRadioSelected = newValue;
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

The documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RadioListTile-class.html#material.RadioListTile.3

This is how I fix the padding:

```
enum ContactSex { nam, nu, khac }

class CreateContactScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = './create_contact';
  @override
  _CreateContactScreenState createState() => _CreateContactScreenState();
}

class _CreateContactScreenState extends State<CreateContactScreen> {
  ContactSex _contaxtSex = ContactSex.nu;
  final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'TẠO LIÊN HỆ',
          style: kHeaderTextStyle,
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: Text('XONG', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 20.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _form,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Tên*',
                ),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                  // TODO: when submit this text field
                },
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Hãy nhập tên cho liên hệ.';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  // TODO : when save the whole form
                },
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Họ',
                ),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                  // TODO: when submit this text field
                },
                // validator: (value) {
                //   if (value.isEmpty) {
                //     return null;
                //   }
                //   return null;
                // },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  // TODO : when save the whole form
                },
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Số điện thoại*',
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                  // TODO: when submit this text field
                },
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Hãy nhập số điện thoại cho liên hệ.';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  // TODO : when save the whole form
                },
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Email',
                ),
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                  // TODO: when submit this text field
                },
                // validator: (value) {
                //   if (value.isEmpty) {
                //     return null;
                //   }
                //   return null;
                // },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  // TODO : when save the whole form
                },
              ),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Giới tính',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        LabeledRadio(
                          label: 'Nữ',
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                          groupValue: _contaxtSex,
                          value: ContactSex.nu,
                          onChanged: (ContactSex newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              _contaxtSex = newValue;
                            });
                          },

                        ),LabeledRadio(
                          label: 'Nam',
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                          groupValue: _contaxtSex,
                          value: ContactSex.nam,
                          onChanged: (ContactSex newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              _contaxtSex = newValue;
                            });
                          },

                        ),LabeledRadio(
                          label: 'Khác',
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                          groupValue: _contaxtSex,
                          value: ContactSex.khac,
                          onChanged: (ContactSex newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              _contaxtSex = newValue;
                            });
                          },

                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LabeledRadio extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final EdgeInsets padding;
  final ContactSex groupValue;
  final ContactSex value;
  final Function onChanged;

  const LabeledRadio(
      {this.label, this.padding, this.groupValue, this.value, this.onChanged});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        if (value != groupValue) {
          onChanged(value);
        }
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: padding,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Radio<ContactSex>(
              groupValue: groupValue,
              value: value,
              onChanged: (ContactSex newValue) {
                onChanged(newValue);
              },
            ),
            Text(label),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set the "dense" property to true, example:

```
RadioListTile<String>(
   title: "My radio",
   dense: true, // <= here it is !
   value: '1',
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use RadioListTile and remove extra padding, by default it's 18

`RadioListTile(contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0)),`
OR

```
RadioListTile(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0), 
            value: null, 
            groupValue: null,
            onChanged: null,
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

you should achieve this manually like
make a group of `Radio()` and `Text()` and wrap with `InkWell()` for state handling. now remove extra space of radio by `materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,` That's it. Get idea by sample code.

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _radioVenue = 0;
        });
      },
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Radio(
            materialTapTargetSize:
                MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
            activeColor: primaryColor,
            groupValue: _radioVenue,
            onChanged: (value) {},
            value: 0,
          ),
          Text('From our list')
        ],
      ),
    ),
    InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          _radioVenue = 1;
        });
      },
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Radio(
            materialTapTargetSize:
                MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
            activeColor: primaryColor,
            groupValue: _radioVenue,
            onChanged: (value) {},
            value: 1,
          ),
          Text('From our list')
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

We covered both both the issues in this sample.

1. Removed extra spaces.
2. whole group is selectable radio + text, Now it behaves like `RadioListTile()`.

Comment: Using GestureDetector instead of InkWell here would be more correct

Answer (score 1):

[image: I set dense to true in the RadioListTile and wrap it with SizedBox widget, then you can set the height and width, It works great]

I set dense to true in the RadioListTile and wrap it with SizedBox widget, then you can set the height and width, It works great

Comment: Please don't post images (or links to images) of code. Anything text-based (code) should be posted directly into the answer and [formatted properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). By posting images we are not able to copy your code to reproduce it. Also, it is not searchable so others can find your answer easily. For more, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/6045800)

Answer (score 1):

You can set contentPadding to EdgeInsets.zero and for removing horizontal padding between the title and radio, you can wrap the title into a transform widget and provide a negative x transform as this.[image]

Answer (score 0):

glad to answer
I was looking for same question and ended up on Flutter Documentation
I was working on Column and RadioListTile and I faced same issue, there's a horizontal padding between content inside RadioListTile

So, here it's the answer
Looking for this documentation ! [RadioListTile content padding](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RadioListTile/contentPadding.html)

Just add `contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0)` and here you go, there's no horizontal padding anymore

Answer (score 0):

Just copy paste this code and enjoy

```
 Container(
                  height:35,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Radio(
                        groupValue: data.selected,
                        value: e,
                        onChanged: (DataBindModel? value) {
                          listener.value = MultiChoiceData(selected: value, items: listener.value.items);
                          onChanged(value);
                          onSelected(value);
                        },
                      ),
                      Text(
                        e.value,
                        style: body14,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
```

Comment: Such answer would be of better quality if it explained the code intention in a sentence or two. As a rule of thumb. And what is `MultiChoiceData`? Where it comes from?

Answer (score -1):

Copy the `RadioListTile` code and create your on new new file and paste it in there.

Remove the imports causing errors:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart'; // leave it
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; //add
import 'list_tile.dart'; //remove
import 'radio.dart'; //remove
import 'theme.dart'; //remove
import 'theme_data.dart'; //remove
```

Then add the following padding to it, like this:

```
//Inside the file locate this widget and Add the padding or remove it. I needed to remove it and add 5. 
   return MergeSemantics(
      child: ListTileTheme.merge(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only( // Add this  
          left: 5,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          top: 0
        ),
        selectedColor: activeColor ?? Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        child: ListTile(
          leading: leading,
          title: title,
          subtitle: subtitle,
          trailing: trailing,
          isThreeLine: isThreeLine,
          dense: dense,
          enabled: onChanged != null,
          onTap: onChanged != null  && !checked ? () { onChanged(value); } : null,
          selected: selected,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

then Import the file into your project like this:

```
import 'package:Project_Name/common/customComponets/custom_radio_list_tile.dart' as CustomRadioListTile;
```

Then use it like this:

```
CustomRadioListTile.RadioListTile(); // and that's how I managed to do it. Thought I should share.
```

Answer (score -1):

This is my way of reducing the space. I have three Radio in one row.

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: RadioListTile(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        value: DayoffType.Range,
        groupValue: _dayoffType,
        title: Transform.translate(offset: const Offset(-18, 0), child: Text('Range')),
        onChanged: (DayoffType? val) {
          setState(() {
            _dayoffType = val!;
          });
        },
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(...Radio2...),
    Expanded(...Radio3...)
  )
```