# How to change the padding of Radio or RadioListTile in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to do some ui customization, but I don't figure out how to reduce the padding of a Radio or RadioList in Flutter.

Can we do it ?

Comment: Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66548016/9167102) answer to achieve what you want

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you are using `RadioListTile` then set `dense` to `true`.

If it's a `Radio` then `materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap` will reduce the size.

Otherwise, make your own.

Comment: `dense: true` not able to solve my problem in case of `RadioListTile`. Thanks.

Answer (score 43):

set these Radio properties:

```
visualDensity: const VisualDensity(
  horizontal: VisualDensity.minimumDensity,
  vertical: VisualDensity.minimumDensity,
),
```

and

```
materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
```

Comment: This should be the correct marked answer! Thanks for it! :)

Comment: @ChristianX yes

Comment: nice clean pertfect answer

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Radio, add property

```
visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: x, vertical: y),
```

Where -4 <= x <= 4, and -4 <= y <= 4

Answer (score 1):

this worked great for me...

```
RadioListTile(
  title: Transform.translate(
           offset: const Offset(-12, 0),
           child: Text(Text'),
         ),
         value: ... 
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the Radio widget in a SizedBox this allows you to control the padding around the Radio widget.

```
SizedBox(
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    child: Radio(
         value: true,
         groupValue: _isSubscription,
         onChanged: (_) {
             setState(() {
                _isSubscription = true;
             });
         },
         // this no longer has any effect on the size
         materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
         ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Below Solution worked for RadioListTile. Although it hasn't remove the space between radio button and title but it looks good because it removes all sorrounding spaces.

```
Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
          color: accentColor.withOpacity(0.45),
        ),
        child: RadioListTile(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          visualDensity: const VisualDensity(
            horizontal: VisualDensity.minimumDensity,
            vertical: VisualDensity.minimumDensity,
          ),
          dense: true,
          title: Text('Male'),
          value: 'Male',
          groupValue: gender,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              gender = value;
            });
          },
        ),
      )
```

[image]